# Why is it not possible to extract text from list

Tags: java, collections

Why am I not able to extract the index of list element??

```
protected void writeString(String string, 
                           List<TextPosition> textPositions) 
      throws IOException {
   System.out.println("string:"+ string); 
   // Outputs string:Hello world 
   System.out.println("text"+ textPositions); 
   // Outputs text:[H, e, l, l, o,  , w, o, r, l, d,  ]
   System.out.println("indexofchar:"+ textPositions.indexOf('w'));
   // Outputs indexofchar -1
}

string:Hello world 
text:`[H, e, l, l, o,  , w, o, r, l, d,  ]`.
```

I expected the output of `indexofchar` to be 6, but the actual is -1

Comment: Please format your code as a code block, so that it becomes readable. Missing linebreaks in combination with `//` make it completely unintelligible. Ideally, remove pointless comments. My guess is that `textPositions` isn't a list of characetrs, so you won't find `'w'` in there.

Comment: Because you list contains `TextPosition`s, not `char`s.

Comment: How it is compile for you ?

Comment: @manfromnowhere simply `List.indexOf(Object o)`

Comment: @J-Alex FYI  OP shows `char`

Comment: Nothing is impossible in mutable code.

Comment: @manfromnowhere - autoboxing.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a character literal to every `TextPosition` item in the list. This will not work. You need to compare and instance of `TextPosition('w')` to each item in the list. And in order to do so, you need to override `hashCode` and `equals`.

```
System.out.println("indexofchar: " + textPositions.indexOf(new TextPosition('w'))); // 6
```

### Example

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PositionFinder {
    private static final List<TextPosition> stringToTextPositions(String s) {
        return Arrays.asList(s.split("")).stream().map(c -> new TextPosition(c.charAt(0))).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) {
        System.out.println("string: " + string);
        System.out.println("text: " + textPositions);
        System.out.println("indexofchar: " + textPositions.indexOf(new TextPosition('w'))); // 6
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Hello world";
        List<TextPosition> textPositions = stringToTextPositions(text);
        new PositionFinder().writeString(text, textPositions);
    }
}
```

Not sure what your's looks like, but here is a basic POJO from what I understand so far.

```
public class TextPosition {
    private char value;

    public TextPosition(char value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + this.value;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        TextPosition other = (TextPosition) obj;
        if (value != other.value) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Character.toString(this.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it not possible to extract text from list.

It is not clear what you mean "extract text".  But clearly `TextPosition` objects are NOT text, so what you have here is not a list of text.

---

Either way, this expression is not going to work.

```
   textPositions.indexOf('w')
```

The `textPositions` object is a `List<TextPosition>`.  That means that the `indexOf` method takes an `Object` as argument: see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)).

You are calling it with a character literal as an argument.  That is primitive value not a reference value, but Java will autobox it to `Character` object.

So now you are searching for a `Character` in a list of `TextPosition` instances.  No `Character` instance can *possibly* be equal a `TextPosition` instance.  So, naturally `indexOf` will always return `-1`.

---

So ... how would you search for a character in a list of `TextPosition` objects?   Well, assuming<sup>1</sup> that `TextPosition` is actually `org.apache.pdfbox.util.TextPosition` ([javadoc](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/TextPosition.html)), we see that it has a `getCharacter()` method that returns 
"the string of characters stored in this object".

So we could do something like this:

```
    String w = Character.toString('w');
    for (int i = 0; i < textPositions.size(); i++) {
        if (textPositions.get(i).character().equals(w)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
```

This could probably be done more elegantly using streams ...

---

<sup>1 - If my assumption about `TextPosition` is incorrect, there should be a way to extract the characters denoted by the position in some form.</sup>